# When implementing a "onReferences" with visual-studio-language-server, how do I search through the content of the files in the workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol, typescript-language-server

I'm currently implementing `onReferences` on the server side of a language server.  When a user right clicks on some custom syntax in a markdown file, I want to be able to use that syntax to search for other occurances of strings elsewhere in the workspace.

```js
connection.onReferences((params) => {
    // I can get the syntax here from the client through params and the document manager
    // but I only have access to the document manager and the open documents.

    // I want to be able to return a location from a possibly unopened file elsewhere

    return null;
});
```

Since I know this happens all the time with the ts-server (click on an interface name and find all occurances) I know this is surely possible.  What general strategy am I missing that I can obtain locations of strings elsewhere?

Comment: @revision#1: You tagged with [tag:typescript-lanugage-server]... but what does this question have to do with that? If that tag isn't actually related here, please remove that tag.

Comment: I mention that ts-server somehow is able to index types and other information to be available when looking up references, so I was hoping someone there might be able to explain how that's so.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/typescript-language-server/typescript-language-server/blob/b081112f12a35fa70aae3a134191dea025de64da/src/lsp-server.ts#L750-L772 ?